# Python holtwinter: ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, forecasting

I'm trying to implement holtwinter using python 3.7. So I used [this link](https://towardsdatascience.com/holt-winters-exponential-smoothing-d703072c0572) & I wrote code following the link. But when I'm trying to execute below line

```
model = HWES(df_train, seasonal_periods=12, trend='add', seasonal='mul')
fitted = model.fit()
```

I got the error message

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()
```

Can you suggest me how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is a case here, but is seems similar to an error when you are using numpy and since panda is built on numpy it may be the same case. So in numpy this kind of error appears when

```
a = np.asarray([[1,2],[3,4]])

if a <2 # would give an error

instead what you would have to do is

np.any(a>2) # for any element greater than 2 
np.all(a>2) # for all elements greater than 2
```

Check if in the code before you don't have any statement like that

Comment: Nope, I'm getting error for this line only, & this is as per the code given in the link